# Is the product between proportionality constant and vector defined?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, vectors

$$
 \delta {U} = - \int F \cdot ds
         = -k \int s \cdot ds
         = -1/2 ks^2 \tag{i}$$
In ($i$) is there is a dot product between spring constant $k$ and deviation $s$?
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Use \ instead of / .

Comment: it would be useful is you used vector signs where appropriate.  Right now you’re working with scalars, so there’s no do product anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $k$ is a scalar quantity so a dot product between it and a vector is undefined. It's just normal multiplication.

Proper notation for what you wrote above is actually:

$$
 \delta {U} = - \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}
         = -k \int\vec{s} \cdot d\vec{s}
         = -\frac{1}{2} ks^2 \tag{i}$$

(assuming that s and ds are in the same direction). That should make clearer where the actual dot product occurs